# Getting GIDs from any Android Application

Tags: android, process

Whenever we start any Activity, we get information about the uid, gid, etc, something like this:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1986): Start proc app.processName for activity hostingNameStr: pid=3641 uid=10109 gids={3003, 1007}
```

Now using PackageManager, we can get the packageName, uid and pid something like this:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm
                .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d("ME", "packageInfo is  :" + packageInfo);
    Log.d("ME", "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Log.d("ME", "Package process for " + packageInfo.packageName+"-->" + packageInfo.processName);
    Log.d("ME", "Package uid for " + packageInfo.packageName+"-->"+packageInfo.uid);
}
```

But here, I'm not able to get the gid and so was wondering whether getting gid like this is even possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to have a look at the methods that are provided by `Process` class. For instance, in your case `getGidForName(String name)`. It returns int values, GID, but I do not know how to select  the list of all gids.

**EDIT:**
I was a bit confused with applicationInfo. You can use [PackageManager's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) method getPackageGids(String packageName) or you can get all PackageInfo and then read value of the `gids` field.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. However, when I'm using getGidForName(String name), I'm getting just 1 integer, instead of an array,and PackageInfo does not have the gids field. But getPackageGids is working smoothly !!

Comment: hey Yury what do we pass as name argument to the function getGidForName(String name) ?